# Power cut out in the middle of an update. Weird errors now from `sudo dpkg --configure -a` on `systemd:amd64` stuff. How to fix? (Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, apt, dpkg, dependencies, systemd

So my power cut out in the middle of an update,
and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is just telling me about errors it can't automatically fix with some `systemd:amd64` stuff.

This is all I have to work from:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-systemd:amd64:
 libnss-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.42); however:
  Package systemd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.42); however:
  Package systemd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnss-systemd:amd64
 libpam-systemd:amd64
```

And honestly... I really don't know where to start.

I mean, if I just took the error message `Package systemd is not installed` at face-value,
then I would simply try `apt-get install systemd`,
but I'm feeling kind of suspicious that it might be more complicated
("If the tool was good enough to diagnose the problem automatically, shouldn't it be good enough to *fix* it automatically?"),
and I don't want to risk making anything worse,
so I figured I should check with a human being first.

What should I do?

---

EDIT: added after following the directions in [@guiverc's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271211/power-cut-out-in-the-middle-of-an-update-weird-errors-now-from-sudo-dpkg-con#comment2153139_1271211)

```
$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.914 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 221157 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_237-3ubuntu10.42_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (237-3ubuntu10.42) over (237-3ubuntu10.41) ...
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
```

and

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 88,7 kB in 2s (56,6 kB/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
47 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

[weird side-note: Apparently it's using archives in Germany, even though I'm in Canada? Wonder if I should fix that somehow...]

Comment: I'd `sudo apt -f install` and see if it fixes it. I may also `sudo apt update` (reading output looking for any errors) before I run the `--fix-broken` depending on where it was in the upgrade process when you lost power, but from your description I'd likely `apt -f install` first.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks! I did that (edited Q to add at the end the output of those). So I should just do `apt-get install --fix-broken` now?

Comment: the `sudo apt -f install` is just a lazy way of using the `--fix-broken` option.  I was using the full term the second time but my fingers shortened it the first time (when less deliberate and typing what I'd type into a terminal..)  If you've `sudo apt update` with no errors, then `full-upgrade` again with no errors, I'd reboot and test your system expecting it to be all good.  (okay I may not reboot, I'd likely evaluate if a reboot was necessary; or a login was necessary etc.. but reboot is easier than describing what I'd do; *systemd makes reboot likely*..)